# iOS8 adding UIViewController's View to another UIViewController's. Background is always white

Tags: ios, iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, background

Can't recall if I have tried this before, and it may be lack a experience with iOS8 OR the dumbest of details I'm missing:

// instantiated from a Storyboard
// c1 uses size classes and auto-layout

```
UIViewController *c1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewController .......
```

// from a nib, using Struts
    UIViewController2 *c2 = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNib.....

```
c2.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
.
.
[c1.view addSubview:c2];
c2.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

No matter where I assign the clearColor (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidLayoutSubview), c2's background is always white

(I have set c2 color to some temp values just to make sure it's not my eye playing on me, c1's background is very very light)

what am I missing? would it have to be with the appDelegate's window?

Sorry I can't post a screenshot here, app belongs to client under NDA, but any help is appreciated.